# Bash/shell make second column red

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, colors

I have function in my `~/.bashrc` I recently upgraded:

```bsh
dircat() {
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Directory tree required, eg: dircat /sys/class/drm/*/status"
        echo "          or: dircat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*"
        echo "          or: dircat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/*"
        echo "NOTE: Only use 'dircat' on directories containing one line files."
        return 1
    fi

    prefix="$1"                         # Initial match is file 1's name
    len="${#1}"                         # Max compare length is file 1's name
    for file in "$@" ; do               # For every filename in '*' glob
        for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do     # Find longest common prefix
            [[ "${prefix:i:1}" == "${file:i:1}" ]] && continue   # matching
            prefix="${prefix:0:i}"      # All the matching characters
            prefix="${prefix%\/*}/"     # Characters up to last "/"
            len="${#prefix}"            # New compare length for next filename
            break
        done
    done

    paste <(ls "$@") <(cat "$@") | column -s $'\t' -t | sed "s#$prefix##g"

} # dircat ()
```

I'd like to further enhance it by making the second column (or last column if you will) red:

[image: dircat output.png]

Comment: maybe something like `<(printf '\e[0;31m%s\e[0m\n' $(cat "$@"))`

Comment: @bac0n That works great! The only thing is to make it **bold** red.

Comment: it was red at least :)= ...  '\e[31m%s\e[0m\n'

Comment: @bac0n It's working now. I upvoted 3 of your answers as a reward :)

Comment: @bac0n Thanks for editing the answer and making the control sequence 8 characters shorter!

Answer (score 1):

Using [bac0n's](https://askubuntu.com/users/986805/bac0n) comment I replaced:

```
paste <(ls "$@") <(cat "$@") | column -s $'\t' -t | sed "s#$prefix##g"
```

with:

```
paste <(ls "$@") <(printf '\e[1;91m%s\e[0m\n' $(cat "$@")) | \
    column -s $'\t' -t | sed "s#$prefix##g"
```

Now it displays as desired:

[image: dircat output 2.png]